# How do I make something the first option when searching?

Tags: google-search, google-chrome, search-engine

So, say I am going to try searching up Twitter for example, but when I type in the letter `t` a Google search for `tilt` appears as the first option. How can I make it so that when I type in the letter `t`, Twitter is the first option? So I can just type `t` and then <kbd>enter</kbd>.

[image: when I type "t" into the search bar.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- paste this into your address bar: **`chrome://settings/searchEngines`**
- add your search engine: **`https://twitter.com/search?q=%s`**

  [image: 0]

  [image: 0]
- usage:

  - type **`t`**
  - press **<kbd>`spacebar`</kbd>** key
  - type the term you search for
  - press **<kbd>`enter`</kbd>** key